# can i clarify my doubt with this site?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

This question may be stupid but if you can help me out I'll be very appreciative and would like to share more of things with this site. Since the day I visit am addicted to even though i could not provide an answer even of basic ones but it really is useful in my studies.

I just want to know wether this site miyodea is of which type: (a) jews orthodox (b) contemporary (c) reformist (d) zionist (c) others
And my next doubt is whether the halakha provided are of 
(a) askenazi  (B) sefardi (c) other

I hope you dont mind am just trying to relief from unwanted site

Comment: Also welcome to Mi Yodeya. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: In theory, it is supposed to be non denominational and there are posts from all backgrounds. In practice, it's Ashkenazi orthodox centric. It's not uncommon to ask a question on halakha and be given an Ashkenazi minhag or chumrah. It also happens that answers given that conflict with that tradition are down voted or ignored. It's the user's responsibility to check the sources and read all the answers. Frequently, the best answers are poorly rated and not the "check mark" answer.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

The first thing you should know is that Mi Yodeya does not give personal, halachic advice.  That should always come from your rabbi.  We ask and answer lots of questions about halacha, and also about text, Jewish living, practical how-to, and a lot more.  Think of Mi Yodeya as a discussion, perhaps in a study hall, among people from all sorts of different communities -- learn from them, share with them, but take practical questions (perhaps informed by what you learn here) to your rabbi.

Now, to your question.  Mi Yodeya has users from across the Jewish spectrum.  Most who post are Orthodox, but quite a few are not.  We have Ashkenazim, Sefardim, Mizrachi, Teimani, and probably others.  We even have some non-Jews.  The site welcomes all who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition or who want to know more, and does not assume or enforce a theological position beyond that.

We place a great emphasis on sources, so that the  community from which any individual hails is less important.  If I answer a question and cite Rashi or the Rambam or Shulchan Aruch or some other source, then *my* Jewish community shouldn't be particularly relevant -- you can look at the cited sources yourself and decide if I got it right.

We all want to make a great collection of well-supported, well-presented questions and answers.  We are also (almost) all anonymous people on the Internet, so you shouldn't just take our word for something important without looking into it yourself.

Comment: Just wondering: Is there a separate site for Karaites, where Rashi/Rambam/Shulchan Aruch etc. are not acceptable sources?

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot not on Stack Exchange currently, though I think I've seen proposals on Area 51, the "proposal/staging ground" site for new sites.  We do get questions sometimes that limit the range of sources -- what does the Rambam say about X, what specifically-Sefardic sources apply to Y, etc.  Perhaps you can scope some of your questions that way.  Questions that ask for only biblical sources (no commentaries), though, don't tend to fare well, because to most of the community the oral law has equal standing to the written law and separating them isn't common.

Comment: It's not that I have questions to ask; just wondering. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot sorry for my misunderstanding!  I just scanned the list of [Area 51 proposals for culture sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/3/culture) and I don't see one about Karaites.  (Religion sites usually show up under culture, but there are other categories that I didn't scan.)

Comment: Am in place where no rabbis are available even for voice calls since am enjoying your site i hope that they are provided with the specific custom toda rabba

Comment: @Yamin You can always email a Rabbi. As Monica said, this site isn't in place of a Rabbi